# How to replace generic function with another one?

Tags: functions, replacement

I have complicated expression in terms of derivatives of a multivariable function `F[x,y,z]` say

```
D[F[x,y,z],x]^2  + D[F[x,y,z],y]^2
```

I want to change the generic function `F[x,y,z]` to another completely generic, now single-variable function `G[x]` . How do I do this?

I have tried `/.{F->G[x]}`    ,`/.{F[x,y,z]->G[x]}`    ,`/.{F->Function[x,G]}` `/.{F[x,y,z]->Function[x,G]}`   ...

Obviously I can’t afford to individually replace the various derivatives by hand...

UPDATE: While I got some good answers, I also managed to find what I was looking for!
The rule `/.{ F -> Function[{x,y,z},G[x]] }` does the trick and (for me at least) is significantly more intuitive than @lilyric and @lukaslang ’s answer

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of how you tries to do the replacement? Concretely, I would have expected your second attempt to (at least partially) work

Comment: For instance this? https://imgur.com/a/WPL8B2c

Comment: `F` should be replaced by a function of three variables, not a function of one, imo.

Comment: The UPDATE is what I had in mind. Of course, it's equivalent to @Lukas's answer, that answer being the anonymous version.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight your comment says the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FullForm` of derivative is

```
D[F[x,y,z],x]//FullForm
(*Derivative[1,0,0][F][x,y,z]*)
```

so you can either prevent (say `Inactivate` the derivative

```
Inactivate[D[F[x,y,z],x]^2  + D[F[x,y,z],y]^2,D]/.{F[x,y,z]:>G[x]}//Activate
(*(G^\[Prime])[x]^2*)
```

or match the `FullForm` of derivative

```
D[F[x,y,z],x]^2  + D[F[x,y,z],y]^2/.{Derivative[a_,b_,c_][F][x,y,z]:>D[G[x],{x,a},{y,b},{z,c}]}
(*(G^\[Prime])[x]^2*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Could you please explain how/why the second works? Coming from Maple this seems needlessly complicated, I would’ve expected a simple ‘ F[x,y,z]->G[x] ‘ does the trick ...

Comment: 1. when evaluating `foo/.F[x,y,z]->G[x]`, MMA search all subparts of `foo` (from the outer level to inner) matching `F[x,y,z]` exactly.

Comment: @Johnny 2 in MMA, the order of evaluation matters. `D[foo,x]/.F[x,y,z]->G[x]` will first evaluate `D` and get stuffs like `Derivative[1,0,0][F][x,y,z]`, which doesn't match with `F[x,y,z]`

Comment: @lukaslang has provided a simpler solution. For the order of evaluation, the documentation `tutorial/Evaluation` is a good start, see also the many nice answers on this forum.

Comment: I see, I thought these completely symbolic derivatives were treated as Inert internally.

Comment: @Johnny Besides `FullForm`, you can also use `Trace`-like functions to see part of intermediate result.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `F->(G[#]&)`:

```
D[F[x,y,z],x]+D[F[x,y,z],y] /. F->(G[#]&)
(* G'[x] *)
```

The reason this works (and your attempts don't) is that `D[F[x,y,z],x]` evaluates to `Derivative[0,0,1][F][x,y,z]`. So all the `F[...]->...` type rules don't even match. What you need is to replace the lonely `F` with `G`: this can in principle be done with just `F->G`, but of course that doesn't tell Mathematica about the number of arguments. `G[#]&` fixes this: This is a function that ignores all but the first argument, so `G[#]&[x,y,z]` results in `G[x]`. The rest is up to Mathematica, which manages to simplify the resulting derivates.

Comment: I see! What If I wanted to replace it with G[y,z] tho?

Comment: `F->(G[#2,#3]&)` should work

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.